# PDO prepared statement isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm finding that my PDO MySQL insertion isn't working

The basic format of it is:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (id, email_hash, dob, 1, 6, 10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

It actually comes like this:

```
$InsertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `my_table` (id, email_hash, dob, $NumbersString) VALUES (?, ?, ?, $QuestionMarkString)");
$InsertQuery->execute(array("$ID, $hashed_email, $dob, $YesNoString"));
```

The variable `$QuestionMarkString` fills in (correctly) the number of question mark placeholders.

The variable `$YesNoString` is a string of "1"s of appropriate length to act as markers in the database.

So even when I can see that the first part of the query successfully becomes formed as:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (id, email_hash, dob, 1, 6, 10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

... and the content of the execute array successfully becomes:

```
52, $2y$10$h9yXWUd8edQVMTSwZrX7T.pJ/C1pLDE9b081OtGmG6nbAtXr7lASK, 29062016, 1, 1, 1
```

.. the insert still doesn't happen.  I get a PHP error saying:

> PHP Warning:  PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 6, 10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line [etc]

Comment: I don't think you need the double quotes surrounding your array values, do you?

Comment: Quite right - but when I correct that, same result.

Comment: What is `$NumbersString`? The `'1` should be indicating something is up with that value..

Comment: You do not actually have columns named 1, 6 and 10 - right? (If you had, you would have to quote them.)

Comment: It is a series of integers which identify columns of that identity in the database.

Comment: "Numbered" column names are usually a sign of bad database design. You should be able to come up with better, "speaking" column names, that tell something about what data they contain. And if you say there are no better names in this situation, then it is probably as sign you did not _normalize_ properly.

Comment: @CBroe - Yes I have.  I guess that's wrong.  Quote them where?  You mean recast their names in the database? Or...

Comment: In your statement, at the position where they appear as column names. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Can you post the structure of your database? Are there columns named 1, 6 and 10?

Comment: Edit your question to add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which explains in very specific terms the schema you're using. That helps people understand where you're coming from. Obviously, please remove anything that you can't disclose on a public forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$InsertQuery->execute(array($ID, $hashed_email, $dob, $YesNoString));
```

Also, you cannot have columns that [only contain digits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Therefore you need to wrap your columns in backticks `

Comment: @imagina Editted to provide more information on another issue

Comment: The `$YesNoString` it sounds like is suppose to map to the placeholders from `$QuestionMarkString`. That won't happen with this approach. There will are 6 placeholders and 4 values trying to be bound.

Comment: @chris85 Problem is that this question has a combination of errors and bad table design that it's difficult providing an answer that fixes everyone at once

Comment: Yea, there's a lot to fix.

Answer (score 0):

my_table

doesn't contain the columns in $NumbersString (1,6,10)

or you need to add backticks to the column names
(`1`,`6`,`10`)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting backticks (`) around the numeric column names:

```sql
INSERT INTO `my_table` (id, email_hash, dob, `1`, `6`, `10`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```